# ASP.NET Core session objects with binary serialization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a use case to store the huge object in session, which has bunch of private variables (so can't use Json serialization), is there a way to accomplish it ?
does binary serialization work by chance with ISession ?

(i understand its not best practice to store this kind of object in session)

Comment: For what it's worth, private variables can be serialized; you just need to add explicitly `[JsonProperty]` attributes to them.

Comment: actually its too many things to update, as it has multi level objects, just wanted a solution to start things quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ISession` has `Set` and `TryGetValue` methods that both work with `byte[]` to set and get binary values, respectively. You'll to take care of serializing to binary yourself; `ISession` won't handle that for you, but once you have the `byte[]`, you can set it in the session.

Comment: Yes, it works,  pretty much like JSON serialization, when the object changes we needed to explicitly update the session object in order to be in sync with updated data